# Parsing JSON to REST api

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

I parsed the below json string to REST api. When I did a printline, only the first get printed out. How can I make it to the expected result?

**json input**

```
{
    "age": "10",
    "name": "Daniel"
},
{
    "age": "12",
    "name": "Fedrik"
}
```

**Student.java**

```
package pagecode.module.jaxrs;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Student 
{
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Student() {
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

**TestingResource.java**

```
package pagecode.module.jaxrs;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/testing")
public class TestingResource {
    @Path("json")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void consumeJSONRequest(Student s)
    {
       System.out.println("**Received JSON request**");
       System.out.println(" Name : "+s.getName());
       System.out.println(" Age  : "+s.getAge());
    }
}
```

**Current Printline**

```
**Received JSON request**
Name : Daniel
Age  : 10
```

**Expected Printline**

```
**Received JSON request**
Name : Daniel
Age  : 10
Name : Fedrik
Age  : 12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `List<Student>` as a parameter. Then you can only get those data.